# Migrating MySql from server to Docker Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Tags: mysql, docker

I am running MySql 5.7 installed through apt-get not docker on the on an Ubuntu server just fine. I am running a docker image of MySql 8.0.33 just fine on my local environment (a different machine then server). On the server I stopped the MySql Instance and ran the same docker image through docker-compose as so:

```
  mysql-database:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:8.0.33
    command: mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collatio$
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - './volumes/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql'
      - './volumes/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf'
      - './volumes/mysql/sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d'
```

As you can see I have mapped all the mysql data to ./volumes folder that should not interfere with any of the native installed mysq files. The container starts fine. When I try to connect to the container on the server via `sudo mysql` or `sudo mysql -u root -p` I get this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Also, unsure if its related, but my wordpress instance doesn't seem to be able to connect to the MySql8.0.33 instance (even though the db should be restored and proper users created and granted privileges).

I think I'm not understanding something about the native mysql installation and the docker instance and mysql client on the server.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: You need to use a TCP connection. See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/337928/82530). For Wordpress, set the host to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has an answer on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/337928/82530)

Comment: Phil, are you sure this is the same thing, on my local Ubuntu machine (that did not have a previous install of MySql) I can connect to my docker MySql instance without any problem.

Comment: Why don't you try it out first and see. Your local version is probably falling back to TCP because there is no socket file. It also depends on the client you're using. Which one is it?

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.41, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper